# How can I splash before callback in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my piece of code:

```
.factory('Latest', function(EBSheadless) {
  return {
    posts: function() {
      // Call the API, and define the specific endpoint
      return EBSheadlessDrupalAPI.loadEndpoint('views/news.json');
    },
    post: function(posts,id,callback){
      var findpost = {};
      for(var i=0;i<posts.length;i++) {
        findpost[posts[i].nid] = posts[i];
      }
      callback(findpost[id]);
    }
  };
})
```

Its getting right result, e.g:

```
this-is-a-news
```

But I need this links like this (I cannot edit backend):

```
/this-is-a-news
```

So I have to add `/` in my callback. I tried many positions but its not working.
How can I solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you just concatenate string like this `callback("/"+findpost[id]);`.This will return `/this-is-a-news`.

```
post: function(posts,id,callback){
      var findpost = {};
      for(var i=0;i<posts.length;i++) {
        findpost[posts[i].nid] = posts[i];
      }
      callback("/"+findpost[id]);
}
```